# PHP: How to convert this string into an associative using Regular Expressions?

Tags: php, regex

I have many strings like these (HTML ones). Long select/option tags like the following.

```
<option value="93">Afghanistan (93)</option>
<option value="355">Albania (355)</option>
<option value="213">Algeria (213)</option>
<option value="376">Andorra (376)</option>
<option value="244">Angola (244)</option>
<option value="264">Anguilla (264)</option>
```

I intend to convert this into a PHP array like,

```
array("93"=>"Afghanistan (93)","355"=>"Albania (355)","213"=>"Algeria (213)", ...)
```

I've never worked on RegEx in PHP so don't know how to approach this. What code/functions should I be using to convert such data?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/78845

Comment: I think you need to learn RegEx before asking on Stackoverflow. Your question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: @Johnsyweb -- StackOverflow should parse question text strategically for "regex" and "html"; if the condition is satisfied, the user should be redirected there with a confirmation box before posting.

Comment: @Bracketworks: presumably using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic regular expression question.

```
preg_match_all("#\"(\d+)\">((\w+) \(\d+\))<#", $data, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
```

But I think you need

```
preg_match_all("#(\d+)\">(\w+)#", $data, $m);
$result = array_combine($m[1], $m[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
preg_match_all('/<option value="([0-9]+)">(.*?)<\/option>/is', $data, $matches);

$result=array();
foreach($matches[1] as $key=>$value){
    $result[$value]=$matches[2][$key];
}
var_dump($result);
```

I suggest you to use DomDocument class for this kind of work. http://www.php.net/manual/fr/class.domdocument.php

Comment: +1 But instead of: `(.*?)` I'd use the more specific: `([^<]+\(\1\))`. Regex is perfectly ok to use with HTML when the target string is highly specific like this one.